# url link to sharepoint file

Tags: vba, excel, email, url

I'm struggling to get this to work

```
Strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              Sheets.("Email body".Range("B2") & _
              ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
              "<A HREF=""file://" & "Sharepoint location" &   Activeworkbook & _
              """>Click here to review</A>" & _
              "<br><br>Regards"
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Start from the very beginning & line by line. When the code is parsted to VBEditor something like this is shown:

[image]

It means somewhere around the parenthesis there is a problem. In this case the `.` is not quite needed. Then continue. I have achieved something like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim strBody As String

    strBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              Sheets("Email body" & Range("B2")) & _
              ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
              "<A HREF=""file://" & "Sharepoint location" & ActiveWorkbook & _
              """>Click here to review</A>" & _
              "<br><br>Regards"

    Debug.Print strBody

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever working with a big string like this, it can be a good idea to split it a bit and to see where the error is coming from:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim strBody As String

    strBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">"
    strBody = strBody & Sheets("Email body" & Range("B2"))
    strBody = strBody & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>"
    strBody = strBody & "<A HREF=""file://" & "Sharepoint location" & ActiveWorkbook
    strBody = strBody & """>Click here to review</A>"
    strBody = strBody & "<br><br>Regards"

    Debug.Print strBody

End Sub
```

Thus you would see where the error is exactly. I guess there would be some error here:`strBody = strBody & "<A HREF=""file://" & "Sharepoint location" & ActiveWorkbook`, because the `ActiveWorkbook` is an object and you probably need one if its properties. E.g. `ActiveWorkbook.Name`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm getting the problem at this pointStrbody = Strbody & "<A HREF=" & "http://address/Payment%20Requests/Forms/" & ActiveWorkbook